# want to create a android library to access bottomsheet in many projects with a custom layout how do i find the views of the custom layout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-library, bottom-sheet

Sorry if i have arise a dumb question but I am new here

please Guide me I am here in Android field Thank you !
I have successfully created a bottomsheet with a custom layout but i want to find the views of that and set the click events on that

here is my library and main activity code

library code

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog

class ToasterBottomSheet {
     fun BottomSheet(context:Context,layout:Int){

        val BottomSheetDialog= BottomSheetDialog(context,R.style.BottomSheetTheme)
        val sheetView: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout,null)
        BottomSheetDialog.behavior.state=(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
         BottomSheetDialog.behavior.maxWidth

      // I want to find the views of the layout and set the click events on that  how do i  ??


        BottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView)
        BottomSheetDialog.show()


    }
}
```

MainActivity is here

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.bytedigital.mytoaster.ToastMesssage
import com.bytedigital.mytoaster.ToasterBottomSheet

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        
        val text=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
        text.setOnClickListener{
            ToasterBottomSheet().BottomSheet(this,R.layout.botamsheet_layout)
        }
        

    }
}
```